# VHDL Code MAC Unit - How to avoid overflow by summing up two signed signals without adding additional bits

Tags: vhdl

I want to do an code, which accumulates an input signal. This means the input signal is added to the previous value. This is then the output

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all

entity adder is
    port(clock : in std_logic;
         ADD_value : in signed(k-1 downto 0));
         Result: out signed(k-1 downto 0));
end adder;

architecture behavioral of adder is


begin
variable acc_value : signed(k-1 downto 0);
    process(clock)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            acc_value := acc_value + Add_value;
            Result<=acc_value ;
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

The problem is that both variables are signed. If an overflow occurs, the overflow goes from the k-1 position to the k-1 position, means the sign is destroyed. Per example if i have 01111 with the first "0" as sign, and i add "10" it goes to "10001", which is bitwise right, but as a signed wrong, because it is a negative value

I tried things like  `acc_value := resize(acc_value + Result_var,k);` or  `acc_value := to_signed(acc_value + Result_var,k);` but I had the same problem

I want as a result, to keep the data length k in case of an overflow, too. If an overflow occurs, the Result should be set to the maximum possible value in respect to the sign.
This means I dont care if there is an overflow, I then only want then a maximum/minimum value

The maximum (minimum in case of negative value) as a kind of saturation. It is possible to come away from the maximum again, since negative values are allowed too.

Comment: Why is `acc_value` an `inout`? VHDL 2008 allows reading of `out` ports. `inout` is generally only needed for tri-state buffers.

Comment: with `acc_value` and `result_var` being the same length, you are always going to have this problem. Addition of two numbers requires an extra bit to capture overflow. You probably want a temporary value to do overflow detection.

Comment: the "things you have tried" will not work with the code as posted because 1. `acc_value` is not a variable, and you have used a variable assignment and 2. there is no declaration of an object `k`.

Comment: Your code as posted, apart from missing object declaration `k`, you are also missing a use clause for `use ieee.std_logic_1164.all` to make `std_logic` type visible.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. This means you would capture it into a new variable and then resize the variable to the right length?

Comment: Yes. And then you have an extra bit allowed you to check for overflow or underflow

Comment: Resizing signed values implies either clipping off significant bits or sign extending to a longer length and doesn't cure information loss. The accumulator wants to be big enough in the first place. Use separate generics for length specifiers or relate the accumulator to the number of times it can accumulate before being being discarded/reset/loaded (missing here). Note a generic clause or use clause making k directly visible is missing. Don't use mode inout, -2008 mode out ports have the same semantics as mode buffer and can be evaluated.

Comment: "How to avoid overflow" is too vague: please specify the desired behavior. It is a fact overflow happens when the value is max and you increase by one. What happens after that is business logic: i.e. specific for your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I specified the title, the question, my requirements. I corrected the code, too. My requirements are that in case of an overflow i want to set the value to the maximum in respect to the sign. This means the maximum/minimum. I dont want to change the bit length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to accumulate forever. There must a barrier exist, which you could check (and perhaps signal an overflow, if the barrier is exceeded). Your signal acc_value must have the width maximum_bit_width, which represents this barrier (be aware that the signal sum_temp has 1 bit more, see below). Result_var may have still the width k. Then you can code (I changed acc_value from "out" to "buffer" to be able to read it, perhaps you should introduce an intermediate signal and leave acc_value as "out" or use VHDL2008 as suggested):

```
         acc_value : buffer signed(maximum_bit_width-1 downto 0);
…
    process(clock)
        variable sum_temp : signed(maximum_bit_width downto 0);
    begin
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            sum_temp := acc_value(maximum_bit_width-1)&acc_value + Result_var;
            if sum_temp(maximum_bit_width)=sum_temp(maximum_bit_width-1) then
                acc_value <= sum_temp(maximum_bit_width-1 downto 0);
            else
                if sum_temp(maximum_bit_width)=‘0‘ then
                    acc_value <= (‘0‘, others => ‘1‘);
                else
                    acc_value <= (‘1‘, others => ‘0‘);
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

Comment: rather than manually extend `acc_value`, you can use the `resize` function, as this does sign extension for you. `sum_temp :=resize(acc_value, sum_temp'length) + Result_var;` I would also recommend never using `buffer` mode as this can complicate port connections in instantiations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not satisfied with the code. First, I dont see a declaration of "overflow". If it is a signal, I had to add an extra port, what I dont want. My requirements are that in case of an overflow i want to set the value to the maximum in respect to the sign. This means the maximum/minimum. I dont want to change the bit length.

Comment: To "It makes no sense to accumulate forever": There are cases which make sense. See the maximum (minimum in case of negative value) as a kind of saturation. Also, it is possible to come away from the maximum again, since negative values are allowed too.

Comment: @hajo: I have edited the answer, following your ideas .

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution! So glad to have a solution for this. 2 little hints on my site: 1. acc_value <= (‘1‘, (others => ‘0‘)); is giving me an error that on the right site he sees only one element instead of maximum_bit_width-1 elements. 2. dealing with maximum_bit_width-1 and maximum_bit_width was quite confusing for me, i think with writing 'high, or 'length it is better understandable. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @hajo: I have fixed your point 1. by editing the answer, I introduced too many brackets.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am very thankful for your effort and your answer!

Comment: You are welcome, perhaps this is also useful to you: [hdl_fsm_editor](http://www.hdl-fsm-editor.de)